tkinter multiple file selection
I'm designing an interface using Tkinter. I have buttons to select files. I want to have 2 different options for the input button, such as being able to select a single file and selecting multiple files. For output, it is enough to select only one file. But no matter what I did, I could not select more than one file. My entire code is too long. I will share the necessary places.
    from functools import partial
import MultiLingualdeneme as ml
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class UIHelper:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
    def select_input_file(self, input_entry, file_type, title, multiple_files=False):
     
        """Dosya seçici fonksiyonu"""
        # Dosya türlerine göre filetypes belirle
        filetypes = []
        if file_type == "json":
            filetypes = [("JSON files", "*.json")]
        elif file_type == "excel":
            filetypes = [("Excel files", "*.xlsx")]
        elif file_type == "text":
            filetypes = [("Text files", "*.txt")]
        else:
            filetypes = [("All files", "*.*")]
        
        # Çoklu dosya seçimi yapılacaksa, askopenfilenames kullanılır
        if multiple_files:
            files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title=title, filetypes=filetypes,multiple_files=True,multiple=True)
            input_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            if files:
                input_entry.insert(0, ', '.join(files))  # Seçilen dosya yollarını virgülle ayırarak ekle
        else:
            # Tek dosya seçimi yapılacaksa, askopenfilename kullanılır
            file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title=title, filetypes=filetypes)
            input_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            if file:
                input_entry.insert(0, file)  # Seçilen dosya yolunu ekle
    def select_output_file(self, entry, file_type, title, default_extension,multiple_files=False):
        """Çıkış dosyasını seçer ve yolu entry'ye ekler."""
        output_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=default_extension, title=title, filetypes=[file_type])
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, output_file)
        

    

    def create_file_selector(self, label_text, file_type, command, multiple_files=False, default_extension=None):
        """Dosya seçici alan oluşturur ve döndürür."""
        file_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        file_frame.pack(pady=10)
        tk.Label(file_frame, text=label_text).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        entry = tk.Entry(file_frame, width=40)
        entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # 'partial' kullanarak komut fonksiyonunu parametreler ile çağırıyoruz
        if default_extension:
            button_command = partial(command, entry, file_type, multiple_files, default_extension)
        else:
            button_command = partial(command, entry, file_type, multiple_files)
        
        tk.Button(file_frame, text="Dosya Seç", command=button_command).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        return entry
class Tab:
    def __init__(self, frame, title, input_file_type, output_file_type, image_paths, convert_function, 
                 column_name_required=False, target_language_required=False, 
                 description_text="",multiple_files=False):
        self.frame = frame
        self.title = title
        self.input_file_type = input_file_type
        self.output_file_type = output_file_type
        self.image_paths = image_paths
        self.convert_function = convert_function
        self.column_name_required = column_name_required
        self.target_language_required = target_language_required
        self.description_text = description_text
        self.multiple_files=multiple_files
        self.helper = UIHelper(frame)

    def show_ui(self):
        input_entry = self.helper.create_file_selector(
            "Giriş Dosyası:", self.input_file_type,
            self.helper.select_input_file,
            multiple_files=self.multiple_files
        )
        output_entry = self.helper.create_file_selector(
            "Çıkış Dosyası:", self.output_file_type,
            self.helper.select_output_file,
            multiple_files=False,  # Çıkış dosyası için sadece tek dosya seçilecek
            default_extension=".xlsx"  # Çıkış dosyasının varsayılan uzantısı
        )
        convert_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Dönüştür", 
                                   command=lambda: self.convert(input_entry, output_entry))
        convert_button.pack(pady=10)
def create_main_window():
    # Ana pencere oluşturuluyor
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Multilingual")
    root.geometry("800x600")
    
    # Yardımcı sınıf ve model sınıfı oluşturuluyor
    

    # Ana pencere için çerçeve oluşturuluyor
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    
    # Menü çubuğu oluşturuluyor
    menu_bar = tk.Menu(root)

    tales_tab_compare_to_translation = Tab(
        frame,
        "Tales Compare Translations",  # Başlık
        ("JSON files", "*.json"),  # Giriş dosyası türü
        ("JSON files", "*.json"),  # Çıkış dosyası türü
        ["path_to_image1.png", "path_to_image2.png"],  # Görseller
        lambda input_file, output_file, target_language: ml.compare_tales_translations(input_file, target_language, output_file),  # Dönüştürme fonksiyonu
        target_language_required=True,  # Hedef dil girişini aktif eder
        description_text="Verilen iki masal çevirisini karşılaştırır ve farkları gösterir.",  # Açıklama metni
        multiple_files=True  # Çoklu dosya desteği aktif
    )

    tales_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
    tales_menu.add_command(label="Compare Translations", command=tales_tab_compare_to_translation.show_ui)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Tales", menu=tales_menu)
    root.config(menu=menu_bar)

    return root

create_main_window().mainloop()


It is better to provide a [mre].

How is it supposed to be? My code is very complex so I can't share it all.

We don't need you to share your whole code.  We just need you to create a [mre] which shows how self.helper is created (and actually it is not clear what it is). Also what is self.frame inside create_file_selector()?, etc.

Also did you check whether the arguments passed to partial() matches with the function definition of select_input_file()?  What I see is that title is missing.

I updated the topic.

askopenfilenames does not have a multiple_files option.

What I see from your code is that ypu are trying to put all filenames into entry using .join() method. I think you shoul not use variable multiple_files but instead simply get all files from filedialog.
In filedialog user can select using CTRL key multiple files at once, so if it is really essentail in your full program you can use
files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title=title, filetypes=filetypes) if len(files) == 1: #do special functionality for single file elif len(files) > 0: #do special functionality for multiple files else: print("no files have been selected")
Or if the only purpose is to show it in entry you can do:
files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title=title, filetypes=filetypes) if len(files) == 0: print("no files entered") else: input_entry.insert(0, ", ".join(files)
Join method works also when there is only one elemnt in list, it does not append string anywhere in output.

There are few issues in your code:

did not pass the title argument to select_input_file() and select_output_file() when calling partial().
the last two arguments to select_output_file() is reversed when calling partial().
extra argument multiple_files passed to askopenfilenames()

Below is the modified code:
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

class UIHelper:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame

    def select_input_file(self, input_entry, file_type, title, multiple_files=False):

        """Dosya seçici fonksiyonu"""
        # Dosya türlerine göre filetypes belirle
        filetypes = []
        if file_type == "json":
            filetypes = [("JSON files", "*.json")]
        elif file_type == "excel":
            filetypes = [("Excel files", "*.xlsx")]
        elif file_type == "text":
            filetypes = [("Text files", "*.txt")]
        else:
            filetypes = [("All files", "*.*")]

        # Çoklu dosya seçimi yapılacaksa, askopenfilenames kullanılır
        if multiple_files:
            ### removed multiple_files argument
            files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title=title, filetypes=filetypes, multiple=True) 
            input_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            if files:
                input_entry.insert(0, ', '.join(files))  # Seçilen dosya yollarını virgülle ayırarak ekle
        else:
            # Tek dosya seçimi yapılacaksa, askopenfilename kullanılır
            file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title=title, filetypes=filetypes)
            input_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            if file:
                input_entry.insert(0, file)  # Seçilen dosya yolunu ekle

    def select_output_file(self, entry, file_type, title, default_extension, multiple_files=False):
        """Çıkış dosyasını seçer ve yolu entry'ye ekler."""
        output_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=default_extension, title=title, filetypes=[file_type])
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, output_file)

    def create_file_selector(self, label_text, file_type, command, multiple_files=False, default_extension=None):
        """Dosya seçici alan oluşturur ve döndürür."""
        file_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        file_frame.pack(pady=10)
        tk.Label(file_frame, text=label_text).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        entry = tk.Entry(file_frame, width=40)
        entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        ### construct the title
        title = 'Select ' + ('files' if multiple_files else 'a file')
        # 'partial' kullanarak komut fonksiyonunu parametreler ile çağırıyoruz
        if default_extension:
            ### added passing title argument
            ### reversed the last two arguments
            button_command = partial(command, entry, file_type, title, default_extension, multiple_files) 
        else:
            ### added passing title argument
            button_command = partial(command, entry, file_type, title, multiple_files)

        tk.Button(file_frame, text="Dosya Seç", command=button_command).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        return entry

class Tab:
    def __init__(self, frame, title, input_file_type, output_file_type, image_paths, convert_function,
                 column_name_required=False, target_language_required=False,
                 description_text="",multiple_files=False):
        self.frame = frame
        self.title = title
        self.input_file_type = input_file_type
        self.output_file_type = output_file_type
        self.image_paths = image_paths
        self.convert_function = convert_function
        self.column_name_required = column_name_required
        self.target_language_required = target_language_required
        self.description_text = description_text
        self.multiple_files=multiple_files
        self.helper = UIHelper(frame)

    def show_ui(self):
        input_entry = self.helper.create_file_selector(
            "Giriş Dosyası:", self.input_file_type,
            self.helper.select_input_file,
            multiple_files=self.multiple_files
        )
        output_entry = self.helper.create_file_selector(
            "Çıkış Dosyası:", self.output_file_type,
            self.helper.select_output_file,
            multiple_files=False,  # Çıkış dosyası için sadece tek dosya seçilecek
            default_extension=".xlsx"  # Çıkış dosyasının varsayılan uzantısı
        )
        convert_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Dönüştür",
                                   command=lambda: self.convert(input_entry, output_entry))
        convert_button.pack(pady=10)

def create_main_window():
    # Ana pencere oluşturuluyor
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Multilingual")
    root.geometry("800x600")

    # Yardımcı sınıf ve model sınıfı oluşturuluyor


    # Ana pencere için çerçeve oluşturuluyor
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # Menü çubuğu oluşturuluyor
    menu_bar = tk.Menu(root)

    tales_tab_compare_to_translation = Tab(
        frame,
        "Tales Compare Translations",  # Başlık
        ("JSON files", "*.json"),  # Giriş dosyası türü
        ("JSON files", "*.json"),  # Çıkış dosyası türü
        ["path_to_image1.png", "path_to_image2.png"],  # Görseller
        lambda input_file, output_file, target_language: ml.compare_tales_translations(input_file, target_language, output_file),  # Dönüştürme fonksiyonu
        target_language_required=True,  # Hedef dil girişini aktif eder
        description_text="Verilen iki masal çevirisini karşılaştırır ve farkları gösterir.",  # Açıklama metni
        multiple_files=True  # Çoklu dosya desteği aktif
    )

    tales_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
    tales_menu.add_command(label="Compare Translations", command=tales_tab_compare_to_translation.show_ui)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Tales", menu=tales_menu)
    root.config(menu=menu_bar)

    return root

create_main_window().mainloop()

